# Deserialize a List of JObjects into List of .NET Object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a List of JObject getting from a method which I need to convert into a named/defined .NET Object.

```
List<JObject> lst=getData();
```

I need to parse the lst into **List of NamedObject**

something like

```
List<MyModel> _lst=parse(lst)
```

How can I accomplish that?

I know JOBject.toObject will work if a single element. But in my case its JObject array.

Comment: Are you not able to `ToObject()` _each `JObject` element_? How does `getData()` work in the first place? Returning a `List<JObject>` is an awfully odd choice in data structure.

Comment: Unfortunately getData() returning a List<JObject>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct your `List<MyModel>` you may combine [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm) to deserialize a `JObject` with a LINQ [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0) method to project every item in your intermediate `lst` to your model as follows:

```
var modelList = lst.Select(o => o.ToObject<MyModel>()).ToList();
```